# i have used this code but it can't work in gujarati font

Tags: php, html, fonts

I have used this code but it doesn't work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/php; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/php; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML file involved and PHP code as well?

Comment: Don't use it. Also when posting a question actually state what the issue is, instead of "please help me!!" with no content in your question

Comment: You have both those lines in your file? What are you expecting, what are you getting?

Comment: i used gujarati language in my php page so what can i do?

Comment: please copy-and-paste the html file you're using (use a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com))

Comment: http://www.anirdesh.com/Gujarati/Gujarati-Web-Pages.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, open a new text document and change the encoding to UTF-8. The images below show how the encoding is changed to UTF-8 in Windows Notepad, Notepad2, and Notepad++. In Notepad2, you can change the encoding from the File menu. In Windows Notepad, you need to select UTF-8 when saving the document. Although its functions are rudimentary, Windows Notepad will warn you if you try to save a page with Unicode characters in ANSI format.

Please follow this link 100% you will be

http://www.anirdesh.com/Gujarati/Gujarati-Web-Pages.php